# Solving a system of linear differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of linear differential equations, and I am following the instructions given on the [Wolfram Alpha page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveSystemsOfLinearODEs.html).

I am not getting the desired output, as can be seen below:
[image]

In the last line, instead of solving the equation for me, I'm just getting my input back. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica can not solve this coupled ODE's. Btw, you had few syntax issues. it is `Cos` and not `cos`. Same for `Sin`.

You also need to convert the matrix equation to separate equations. But after doing all of this, `DSolve` can not solve them.

```
ClearAll[x, t, y, u, v]
x[t_] := Sin[t]
y[t_] := Cos[t]
A = {{x'[t], y'[t]}, {y'[t], -x'[t]}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
U[t_] = {u[t], v[t]};
system = U'[t] == A.U[t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 system = First@Solve[system, U'[t]] /. Rule -> Equal
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 DSolve[system, U[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

fyi, if you want solution, Maple is able to solve this. But solution are complicated. What does this model represent? Is this an actual physical system?

```
restart;
ode1:=diff(u(t),t)=cos(t)*u(t)-sin(t)*v(t);
ode2:=diff(v(t),t)=-sin(t)*u(t)-cos(t)*v(t);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 dsolve([ode1,ode2],[u(t),v(t)])
```

$$
v \left( t \right) ={\frac {\sqrt {2\,\sin \left( t \right) -1}
 \left( \sqrt [4]{-\sqrt {3}\sin \left( t \right) +3\,\cos \left( t
 \right) +2\,\sqrt {3}}\sqrt [4]{\sin \left( t \right) -2-\sqrt {3}
\cos \left( t \right) } \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{-i/2\sqrt {3}}{\it \_C2}+\sqrt [4]{-\sqrt {3}\sin
 \left( t \right) -3\,\cos \left( t \right) +2\,\sqrt {3}}\sqrt [4]{
\sin \left( t \right) -2+\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right) } \left( \sin
 \left( t \right) +i\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{i/2\sqrt {3}}{
\it \_C1} \right) }{\sqrt [4]{\sin \left( t \right) -2-\sqrt {3}\cos
 \left( t \right) }\sqrt [4]{\sin \left( t \right) -2+\sqrt {3}\cos
 \left( t \right) }}}
$$

and

$$
u \left( t \right) =1/4\,{\frac {-4\,\cos \left( t \right)  \left( 2\,
\sin \left( t \right) -1 \right)  \left( \sqrt [4]{ \left( -\sin
 \left( t \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}-3\,\cos \left( t \right) }
\sqrt [4]{\sin \left( t \right) -2+\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right) }
 \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{i/2
\sqrt {3}}{\it \_C1}+\sqrt [4]{\sin \left( t \right) -2-\sqrt {3}\cos
 \left( t \right) } \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{-i/2\sqrt {3}}\sqrt [4]{ \left( -\sin \left( t
 \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}+3\,\cos \left( t \right) }{\it \_C2}
 \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) -2-\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) -2+\sqrt {3}\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2
 \right) \sqrt {3}-3\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3/4} \left( 
 \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}+3\,\cos \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{3/4}-4\,{\it \_C1}\, \left( \sin \left( t \right) 
+i\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{i/2\sqrt {3}} \left(  \left( -\sin
 \left( t \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}-3\,\cos \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( t \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) -2-\sqrt 
{3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2
 \right) \sqrt {3}+3\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3/4} \left( 
\sin \left( t \right) -2+\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5/4
}-2\,i{\it \_C1}\, \left( 2\,\sin \left( t \right) -1 \right)  \left( 
\sin \left( t \right) +i\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{i/2\sqrt {3}}
\sqrt {3} \left( \cos \left( t \right) -i\sin \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}-3
\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) -2-
\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t
 \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}+3\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3/4}
 \left( \sin \left( t \right) -2+\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{5/4}-{\it \_C1}\, \left( 2\,\sin \left( t \right) -1
 \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{i/2\sqrt {3}} \left( -\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right) +3\,
\sin \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) -2-\sqrt 
{3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2
 \right) \sqrt {3}+3\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3/4} \left( 
\sin \left( t \right) -2+\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5/4
}+{\it \_C1}\, \left( 2\,\sin \left( t \right) -1 \right)  \left( \sin
 \left( t \right) +i\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{i/2\sqrt {3}}
 \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}-3\,\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \cos \left( t \right) +\sqrt {3}
\sin \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2
 \right) \sqrt {3}+3\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3/4} \left( 
\sin \left( t \right) -2+\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5/4
}-4\,{\it \_C2}\, \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{-i/2\sqrt {3}} \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t
 \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}+3\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right) \cos
 \left( t \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) -2+\sqrt {3}\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2
 \right) \sqrt {3}-3\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3/4} \left( 
\sin \left( t \right) -2-\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5/4
}+2\,i{\it \_C2}\, \left( 2\,\sin \left( t \right) -1 \right)  \left( 
\sin \left( t \right) +i\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{-i/2\sqrt {3}
}\sqrt {3} \left( \cos \left( t \right) -i\sin \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}+3
\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) -2+
\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t
 \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}-3\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3/4}
 \left( \sin \left( t \right) -2-\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{5/4}-{\it \_C2}\, \left( 2\,\sin \left( t \right) -1
 \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{-i/2\sqrt {3}} \left( -\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right) -3\,
\sin \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) -2+\sqrt 
{3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2
 \right) \sqrt {3}-3\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3/4} \left( 
\sin \left( t \right) -2-\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5/4
}+{\it \_C2}\, \left( 2\,\sin \left( t \right) -1 \right)  \left( \sin
 \left( t \right) +i\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{-i/2\sqrt {3}}
 \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}+3\,\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \cos \left( t \right) -\sqrt {3}
\sin \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2
 \right) \sqrt {3}-3\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3/4} \left( 
\sin \left( t \right) -2-\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5/4
}}{\sqrt {2\,\sin \left( t \right) -1} \left( \sin \left( t \right) +i
\cos \left( t \right)  \right)  \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) 
+2 \right) \sqrt {3}-3\,\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3/4} \left( 
\sin \left( t \right) -2-\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5/4
} \left(  \left( -\sin \left( t \right) +2 \right) \sqrt {3}+3\,\cos
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3/4} \left( \sin \left( t \right) -2+
\sqrt {3}\cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5/4}\sin \left( t \right) }}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback!! Yes this is the trajectory of the rear end of a bicycle as the front end goes around a circle